# (Linklist in C): : error: conflicting types for ‘addTail’

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers

**This is my code**: I am writing a demo of linklist, but I caught this err.

```
    Document initHead(){
        Document head;
        head = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    Document Input(){
        Document head = initHead();
        int n, id, amount;
        char *name;
        do{
            printf("\nNhap so luong tai lieu = ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
        }while(n <= 0);
     
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            printf("\nNhap thong tin cua tai lieu: ");
            scanf("%d", &id);
            scanf("%s", &name);
            scanf("%d", &amount);
            head = addTail(head, id, name, amount);
        }
        return head;
    }
    Document addTail(Document head, int id, char *name, int amount){
        Document temp, p;// Khai báo 2 node tạm temp và p[20]
        temp = createDocument(id, name, amount);//Gọi hàm createNode để khởi tạo node temp có next trỏ tới NULL và giá trị là value
        if(head == NULL){
            head = temp;     //Nếu linked list đang trống thì Node temp là head luôn
        }
        else{
            p  = head;// Khởi tạo p trỏ tới head
            while(p->next != NULL){
                p = p->next;//Duyệt danh sách liên kết đến cuối. Node cuối là node có next = NULL
            }
            p->next = temp;//Gán next của thằng cuối = temp. Khi đó temp sẽ là thằng cuối(temp->next = NULL mà)
        }
        return head;
    }
    int main()
    {
        printf("\n==Tao 1 danh sach lien ket==");
        Document head = Input();
        printf("\n==Thu them 1 phan tu vao linked list==");
        return 0;
    }
```

**This is my log:**

```
$gcc -o main *.c
main.c: In function ‘Input’:
main.c:48:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘addTail’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         head = addTail(head, id, name, amount);
                ^~~~~~~
main.c:48:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         head = addTail(head, id, name, amount);
              ^
main.c: At top level:
main.c:52:10: error: conflicting types for ‘addTail’
 Document addTail(Document head, int id, char *name, int amount){
          ^~~~~~~
main.c:48:16: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘addTail’ was here
         head = addTail(head, id, name, amount);
                ^~~~~~~
```

I do not know why I caught this conflict, I scan it out, but I can not know why. Pls help me. Thank you guys so much.!

Comment: Have you remembered to actually *declare* the function you call, before you call them? Remeber that in C all symbols *must* be declared before they're used.

Comment: what @Someprogrammerdude means is to use forward declaration of functions

Comment: I have declared it above main() already?? So I dont get you, Can you explain more?

Comment: add  this line on the top of your code  Document addTail(Document head, int id, char *name, int amount); [what is forward declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because you're attempting to call `addTail` before it is declared or defined.

In the `Input` function you're calling `addTail`, but `addTail` hasn't been defined or declared yet.  This results in an implicit declaration of `int addTail()` which conflicts with the read definition.

It's not enough that the function is before `main`, it has to be before *any* function that calls it.

You need to either move `addTail` so that it's before `Input`, or add a declaration for `addTail` before `Input`.